# How to access usercontrol id from the aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol as given below.

```
public partial class lcont : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
  public delegate void mydel(string str);

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  }
  public event mydel myevent;

  public void butt_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (myevent != null)
    {
        myevent(tv.SelectedNode.Value);
    }  
  }
}
```

And a test.aspx which has used the usercontrol of the above.

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <uc1:lcont ID="lcont1" runat="server" />
 <div>
 <asp:Label ID ='lbl' runat="server" Text ="lbl"  />
 </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

Its codebehind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   lcont1.myevent += delegate(string st)
    {
        lbl.Text = st;
    };

}
```

As you can see here i am able to call "lcont1" which is the id of usercontrol in the codebehind of aspx file.

Now the question is: I want to do the same thing but this time with the aspx file that hasn't directly implemented the usercontrol but has inherited the master page which has implemented the usercontrol.

IN other word, the usercontrol is implemented in the master page and the master page is implemented by the aspx page.Now i want to access the usercontrol id in the aspx page just like the above example.Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is this...

Create a public function/property in your `MasterPage` that exposes the `UserControl`

```
public lcont GetLcont1()
{
   return lcont1;
}
```

Then in your `.aspx` you can cast the `MasterPage`

```
MyMasterPage myMaster = (MyMasterPage)Page.Master;
```

Now you should be able to get your `UserControl` and do what you need with it

```
lcont lcont1 = myMaster.GetLcont1();
lcont1.doSomething();
```

---

**Update**

As the OP requires spoon-feeding, here is the code-behind for the `.aspx` page...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Note: replace "MyMasterPage" with the name of your master page class
  MyMasterPage myMaster = (MyMasterPage)Page.Master;
  lcont lcont1 = myMaster.GetLcont1();
  lcont1.myevent += delegate(string st)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is the function GetLcont1() returning actual id of usercontrol? Because i need to access the actual id of usercontrol.

Comment: If you read the code, you'll see that it the instance of the control that is being returned... I shouldn't really need to tell you that.  If you need client ID, then do `lcont1.ClientID` instead of `lcont1.doSomething();`

Comment: What i need to do is just like the codebehind of the code given in the question.The last block of code in the question.

Comment: Is that better... or would you like me to write your entire project for you?

Comment: I have done the same thing `hfm mymaster = (hfm)Page.Master;
        lcont lcont1 =mymaster.getlcont();
        lcont1.myevent += delegate(string st)
        {
            slbl.Text = st;
        };` But its not working..the label is supposed the change but it is remaining the same.So i was asking you.